# override new and member access operator to use custom heap

Tags: c++

I've been working on a little project to learn about how dynamic memory allocation works. I have a global char buffer I'm using as my heap. After reading [these lecture notes](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs241/sp2014/lecture/06-HeapMemory_sol.pdf) I've written Alloc, DeAlloc, MergeBlocks, and SplitBlocks functions for memory management. Alloc and DeAlloc function like malloc and free but for the fact that they write into my heap array. Now that I have them working I am wondering how to overload a simple class to make use of my memory management.

```
// Memory Block structure

// -------------------------------
// |         size       | active | 2 bytes
// -------------------------------  
// |                             | n bytes
// |         payload             |
// |                             |
// -------------------------------
// |        padding              | m bytes (n + m + 4 is a multiple of 8)
// -------------------------------
// |         size       | active | 2 bytes
// -------------------------------

unsigned char heap[2064]; // fake heap

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Omitting a bunch of memory management functions that manage the heap
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------


struct SimpleStruct 
{
    unsigned short x;

    SimpleStruct(unsigned short x) 
    {
        this->x = x;
    }

    // Need to override -> operator but not sure what to do

    void* operator new(size_t size) 
    {
        return (void*)Alloc(size);
    }
};


int main()
{
  SimpleStruct* s = new SimpleStruct(5);
  s->x = 3;
}
```

I feel like I need to do a few things:

First I need to actually store the member variable values on my custom heap

Second I need to make it so that the ->() operator looks in the appropriate location in the heap to find the member variables. I could do this in the constructor but I want them stored on the stack if new isn't used

I've tried looking up info online but I can't seem to find any leads. I'm not even sure that this is possible. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new See the syntax for overloading the operator for single class. Sematics are that it just returns a piece of memory of size atleast `sizeof(T)` that must remain valid until delete is called. There's no need for -> operator, the class itself does not need to know where it's located. Location of member variables is determined as offset to the base address of the pointer at compile time. So `*(p+offset)==(*p).x` .

Comment: My code won't work that way since p actually points to the beginning of a memory block that I've created in a global char array. The block has a header and a footer indicating some metadata about the memory block. Size, isFree, etc.

Comment: @AdamSturge The object will be constructed at the address returned by `operator new`.  If `Alloc` returns a pointer to the beginning of some block that contains metadata, then `operator new` should adjust that pointer before returning it.  Better would be to have `Alloc` return a pointer to the payload area, and have `Dealloc` take such a pointer and adjust it to find the metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object will be constructed at the address returned by `operator new`.  If the address returned by `Alloc` points to the block's metadata, then `operator new` needs to adjust that pointer to that the object doesn't overwrite the metadata:

```
void* operator new(size_t size) 
{
    char* block = (char*)Alloc(size);
    return (void*)(block + 2);
}
```

You'll then need a matching `operator delete` that can find the metadata given a pointer to the payload:

```
void operator delete(void* ptr)
{
    char* block = (char*)ptr - 2;
    DeAlloc(block);
}
```

It's probably a good idea to put those adjustments directly into `Alloc` and `DeAlloc` to prevent possible mistakes from corrupting your heap.  That's exactly what many `malloc` and `free` implementations do, so that's the expected behavior for an allocation function, and it prevents users from needing to know the internal structure of your heap to use it.

Comment: So I notice that *this* does indeed take on the value returned by Alloc. And you are right that they payload does start 2 bytes into the first block. However this->head = head returns "violation writing location 0x0000000000000002." To me this seems like it's trying to write into the real heap's low address range and not my fake heap

Also you're totally right about needing to shift the return by 2. I should hide that detail from the users

Comment: I figured it out after a good nights sleep. I needed to add &heap[0] to the pointers returned by Alloc() so that cpu knew where to write the data

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

```
SimpleStruct s = new SimpleStruct(5);
```

should be:

```
SimpleStruct* s = new SimpleStruct(5);
```

Is this the root of your problem?

You don't need to overload `->`. When you `new` an instance of your class, required memory amount is allocated on the heap and if succeeded your class constructor is called *over* this memory (`this` is a pointer to this memory). Your variables are located inside this memory block and compiler can calculate their location from `this`.

When you implement custom memory allocation, the only difference is that memory is not allocated from the global heap but you give a pointer to some memory. The rest is the same: you have a pointer to your class instance and when you write `this->x` or `s->x` compiler knows how to access this member because it knows its "shift" from the start of instance representation in the memory.

Comment: ah sorry, the * was a typo from when I transcribed the code so that's not the problem.

I don't think that's correct, in that my code doesn't work. My Alloc() function just prepares some space in a global char array. The compiler doesn't know to interpret that it seems